# iOS Storyboard lags and won't open

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, lag, freeze

I have a project that isn't too huge, it has maybe 6-7 different class files and 5 view controllers. However when I try to open the Main.storyboard, Xcode 6 freezes and lags. I'm running an Intel i7 4770k and gtx 780, so my computer should be able to handle something as simple as this. I can open all the class files and everything else fine.

Here is an image of the problem
[image]

I get "Application not responding", and I can open the storyboard on other projects.

Comment: That's pretty vague, but a few of general suggestions. 1) Try cleaning caches via `Shift+Command+K`. 2) Erase your iOS Simulator (`Erase Content and Settings`). 3) Close Xcode and iOS Simulator, then reboot them. 4) Delete your derived data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite common problem that occurs every once in a while in Xcode.
You should try the following: (each may solve it)

- clean the project you are working on using `cmd`+`shift`+`k`
- close (force-quit with `cmd`+`alt`+`esc` if necessary) Xcode & restart
- reboot your Mac
- uninstall Xcode & re-install the newest version of it

Hope that helps :)